# Let $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^k, U_i\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be orthogonal matrices. Show that the product $U = U_1U_2\cdots U_k$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

> Let $U_1,U_2,\dots, U_k\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be orthogonal matrices. Show that the product $U = U_1U_2\cdots U_k$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Note, $U=\prod\limits_{i=1}^kU_i = U_1U_2\cdots U_k$. Then we need to show that $U^TU=I=UU^T$. Showing $U^TU = I$, observe:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        U^TU &= \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^kU_i\right)^T\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^kU_i\right) \\
        &= \left(\prod\limits_{i=-k}^{-1}U_{-i}^T\right)\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^kU_i\right) \\
        &= \left(\prod\limits_{i=-k}^{-2}U_{-i}^T\right)\left(\prod\limits_{i=2}^kU_i\right) \\
        &\vdots \\
        &= U_k^TU_k \\
        &= I
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Now we show $UU^T=I$. Observe:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        UU^T &= \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^kU_i\right)\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^kU_i\right)^T \\
        &= \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^kU_i\right)\left(\prod\limits_{i=-k}^{-1}U_{-i}^T\right) \\
        &= \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}U_i\right)\left(\prod\limits_{i=-k+1}^{-1}U_{-i}^T\right) \\
        &\vdots \\
        &= U_1U_1^T \\
        &= I
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
And hence, $U$ is orthogonal.

Is this a sufficient proof?

Comment: A simpler answer here is probably to show that the product of two orthogonal matrices $A$, $B$ is orthogonal, since $(AB)^TAB = B^T(A^TA)B = B^T I B = I$. Then by induction, a product of any finite number of orthogonal matrices is orthogonal. This is more or less equivalent to your proof, but it's quite difficult to read the product notation when there is all this reversing and cancelling going on.

Comment: That sounds a more desirable route than doing what feels “duplicated” effort… :(

Comment: Note that the ellipsis $\vdot$ is a kind of hidden induction

Comment: I did notice that as I wrote this up.